# Lnk1104 cannot open file debug.obj

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a C++ project in vs 2022 that giving me a lnk1104 error. I have made sure that "debug information format
" is set to Z1, but the debug.obj or the .pdb file is not being created. I am not sure why.
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

This project is being updated from vs 2013 to vs 2022(v143)
I have been working on this error all day and am running out of things to try. Any help would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgVcf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qflT.png

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
 <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
 <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
 <Platform>Win32</Platform>
 </ProjectConfiguration>
 <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
 <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
 <Platform>Win32</Platform>
 </ProjectConfiguration>
 <ProjectConfiguration Include="Template|Win32">
 <Configuration>Template</Configuration>
 <Platform>Win32</Platform>
 </ProjectConfiguration>
 </ItemGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
 <SccProjectName />
 <SccLocalPath />
 <Keyword>MFCProj</Keyword>
 <ProjectGuid>{84200974-822B-4F51-A69C-B007BA2C6E29}</ProjectGuid>
 <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Template|Win32'" 
Label="Configuration">
 <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
 <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
 <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
 <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
 <UseOfMfc>Static</UseOfMfc>
 <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
 <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
 <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
 <UseOfMfc>Dynamic</UseOfMfc>
 <CharacterSet>
 </CharacterSet>
 <PreferredToolArchitecture>
 </PreferredToolArchitecture>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
 <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
 </ImportGroup>
 <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Template|Win32'">
 <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" 
Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" 
Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
 </ImportGroup>
 <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
 <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" 
Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" 
Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.Cpp.UpgradeFromVC60.props" />
 </ImportGroup>
 <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
 <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" 
Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" 
Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)Microsoft.Cpp.UpgradeFromVC60.props" />
 </ImportGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
 <OutDir>.\Debug\</OutDir>
 <IntDir>.\Debug\</IntDir>
 <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
 
<IncludePath>$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSdk_71A_IncludePath);.\source\include;E:\toms_files\repo
s\P&amp;G\Software\Trace source\pag Trace source Apr 23 
2018\pagt2k\project\source\include</IncludePath>
 <LibraryPath>$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(LibraryPath)</LibraryPath>
 
<ExecutablePath>$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86);$(WindowsSdk_71A_ExecutablePath);$(WindowsSDK_Exe
cutablePath);$(VS_ExecutablePath);$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath);$(SystemRoot)\SysWow64;$(FxCopDir);
$(PATH);$(ExecutablePath)</ExecutablePath>
 <LibraryWPath />
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
 <OutDir>.\Release\</OutDir>
 <IntDir>.\Release\</IntDir>
 <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
 <ClCompile>
 <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
 <InlineFunctionExpansion>Default</InlineFunctionExpansion>
 <FunctionLevelLinking>false</FunctionLevelLinking>
 <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
 <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefini
tions>
 <AssemblerListingLocation>.\Debug\</AssemblerListingLocation>
 <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>.\Debug\Trace2000.pch</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>
 <ObjectFileName>.\Debug\</ObjectFileName>
 <ProgramDataBaseFileName>.\Debug\</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
 <PreprocessToFile>false</PreprocessToFile>
 <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;G\Software\Trace source\pag Trace 
source Apr 23 2018_2\pagt2k\project\source\library;E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;G\Software\Trace 
source\pag Trace source Apr 23 
2018_2\pagt2k\project\source\resources;.\source\include;.\source\library;E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;
G\Software\Trace source\pag Trace source Apr 23 
2018\pagt2k\project\$(ConfigurationName);E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;G\Software\Trace source\pag 
Trace source Apr 23 2018\pagt2k\project\source\include;E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;G\Software\Trace 
source\pag Trace source Apr 23 
2018\pagt2k\project\source\resources;E:\toms_files\repos\P&amp;G\Software\Trace source\pag Trace 
source Apr 23 2018\pagt2k\project\source\library;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\VC\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
 </ClCompile>
 <Midl>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
 <TypeLibraryName>.\Debug\Trace2000.tlb</TypeLibraryName>
 <MkTypLibCompatible>true</MkTypLibCompatible>
 <TargetEnvironment>Win32</TargetEnvironment>
 </Midl>
 <ResourceCompile>
 <Culture>0x0409</Culture>
 <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
 </ResourceCompile>
 <Bscmake>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <OutputFile>.\Debug\Trace2000.bsc</OutputFile>
 </Bscmake>
 <Link>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
 <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
 <OutputFile>.\Debug\Trace2000.exe</OutputFile>
 <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
 <AdditionalDependencies>%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
 <AssemblyDebug>
 </AssemblyDebug>
 <ProgramDatabaseFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
 <MinimumRequiredVersion>
 </MinimumRequiredVersion>
 <ShowProgress>LinkVerboseLib</ShowProgress>
 </Link>
 </ItemDefinitionGroup>
 <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
 <ClCompile>
 <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
 <InlineFunctionExpansion>Default</InlineFunctionExpansion>
 <StringPooling>true</StringPooling>
 <FunctionLevelLinking>true</FunctionLevelLinking>
 <Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefini
tions>
 <AssemblerListingLocation>.\Release\</AssemblerListingLocation>
 <PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>.\Release\Trace2000.pch</PrecompiledHeaderOutputFile>
 <ObjectFileName>.\Release\</ObjectFileName>
 <ProgramDataBaseFileName>.\Release\</ProgramDataBaseFileName>
 </ClCompile>
 <Midl>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
 <TypeLibraryName>.\Release\Trace2000.tlb</TypeLibraryName>
 <MkTypLibCompatible>true</MkTypLibCompatible>
 <TargetEnvironment>Win32</TargetEnvironment>
 </Midl>
 <ResourceCompile>
 <Culture>0x0409</Culture>
 <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
 </ResourceCompile>
 <Bscmake>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <OutputFile>.\Release\Trace2000.bsc</OutputFile>
 </Bscmake>
 <Link>
 <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
 <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
 <OutputFile>.\Release\Trace2000.exe</OutputFile>
 
<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>\Trace2K\Project\AgvLib\Release;\Trace2K\Project\TcsLib\Release;%(Add
itionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
 
<AdditionalDependencies>agvlib.lib;tcslib.lib;rpcrt4.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDepende
ncies>
 </Link>
 </ItemDefinitionGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
 <ClCompile Include="Source\Library\Trace2000.cpp" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
 <ResourceCompile Include="Source\Library\AgvLib.rc">
 <AdditionalIncludeDirectories 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Source\Library;%(AdditionalIncludeDirect
ories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
 <AdditionalIncludeDirectories 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Source\Library;%(AdditionalIncludeDirec
tories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
 </ResourceCompile>
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
 <CustomBuild Include="..\Docs\ReleaseNotes.doc" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
 <ProjectReference Include="agvbld\AgvBld.vcxproj">
 <Project>{c14c5a4f-54ca-4e16-baeb-873117304e5b}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="agvctlsd\AgvCtlSD.vcxproj">
 <Project>{25f2e990-80d5-4f20-beb3-afd2f5cf78b9}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="agvctl\AgvCtl.vcxproj">
 <Project>{c707a040-a978-4d8e-a81c-ee36b65988e9}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="agvsta\AgvSta.vcxproj">
 <Project>{9e5af95d-0688-4fd3-87eb-33f82ca10d7b}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="agvsum\AgvSum.vcxproj">
 <Project>{de9d9907-bbc4-436c-9fdb-4e8e9523cecd}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="almmon\AlmMon.vcxproj">
 <Project>{9c6781bc-7de8-4a10-af0c-177688ab2c6d}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="hdl\hdl.vcxproj">
 <Project>{44bf4dc8-4139-4c11-8ada-71b1f75bdac8}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="infsvr\InfSvr.vcxproj">
 <Project>{ddc9336d-e536-4ac7-91ef-1b04ab741531}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="logmon\LogMon.vcxproj">
 <Project>{0ed1f15b-07bb-4868-aef3-9c6480bdbc65}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="LogSearch\LogSearch.vcxproj">
 <Project>{1def9cfa-a6a6-4d29-9e29-635956617b5d}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="logsvr\LogSvr.vcxproj">
 <Project>{8f6e952f-e000-43e4-9f45-135140b30a67}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="msggen\MsgGen.vcxproj">
 <Project>{8ca7261e-ee13-4606-8c0d-499cc5781b28}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="OptComEnetIP\OptComEnetIP.vcxproj">
 <Project>{ffc1d900-5bf5-4c7e-8f65-c3a7add6efdd}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="OptComKTX\OptComKTX.vcxproj">
 <Project>{13738c96-05a7-43ea-b962-b5d227f184f3}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="optcom\OptCom.vcxproj">
 <Project>{1bd5e548-243d-4943-af68-8dc62abb7851}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="optsta\OptSta.vcxproj">
 <Project>{68828d43-fd9f-4324-9507-6ca769abb895}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="ordsta\OrdSta.vcxproj">
 <Project>{b384eecf-6558-4342-8de5-91d45138415a}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="prcmgr\PrcMgr.vcxproj">
 <Project>{e5bac58c-5c79-4964-b681-e3e109310ddd}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="prmedt\PrmEdt.vcxproj">
 <Project>{6b1da190-2b97-4d67-9fa3-c43af992aecb}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 <ProjectReference Include="wait\WAIT.vcxproj">
 <Project>{807ce733-e5e7-4300-a6de-5552fcc30756}</Project>
 <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
 </ProjectReference>
 </ItemGroup>
 <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
 <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
 </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Project cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tcsdef.h"
#include <AgvObject.h>
#include <Windows.h>
//#include "library.h"
//#pragma comment(lib,"AgcLib.lib")

int WINAPI WinMain(  
    HINSTANCE hInstance,              // Instance handle 
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,        // Previous instance handle 
    LPSTR lpszCommandLine,        // Command line string 
    int cmdShow )                       // ShowWindow flag 
{
  AgvObject AObj;

  CString msg;
  CString title;

  title = "Trace2k";

  msg = "Trace2k Version information\n";
  msg +=  AObj.GetResVersion();
  msg += "\nAgvObject Source ";
  //msg += AObj.GetVersion();

  MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow(), msg, title, MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably show us the .vcxproj file. You've probably got some conflicting settings there.

Comment: I added the requested file and the cpp file to the main question. In the cpp file if I comment out AgvObject Aobj declaration and AObj object the project compiles correctly. The header file is AGVObject.h. Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but the file looks extremely messy and contains a lot of outdated stuff. I suggest you just recreate that project file.

Comment: What is interesting is that this is the only header and cpp file that is erroring in one project. This header works in other projects. Which file are you suggesting I recreate trace2000 or AgvObect.cpp? thanks Tom

Comment: The vcxproj project file.

Comment: Thank for the information. This item is just a text string and I have commented it out at the moment. I will try this.